# How to access a value from a list of tuples in erlang and create a new list out of it?

Tags: erlang

The problem is to get the list of first element of each tuple in a list. Erlang is giving me a hard time. How do I add elements dynamically in a list in erlang?

```
I tried to read the list of tuples and store it into another list to get the first element of each tuple in the list.

  getBankList([BankData|T]) ->
    {BankName, Resource}=T,
    createList(BankName),
    getBankList(T).

createList(Name)->
  List = [],
 List2 = [Name|list1].

[{jill,450},
{joe,157},
{bob,100},
{sue,125},
{pat,344}].
```

These are the of tuples, I need the list as:
[jill,joe,bob,sue,pat]

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
List = [{jill,450}, {joe,157}, {bob,100}, {sue,125}, {pat,344}]
```

then

```
[Name || {Name, _} <- List]
```

will get `[jill, joe, bob, sue, pat]`. This is *list comprehension*, read more about it [here](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`lists:unzip/1` function](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#unzip-1) to split a list of pair tuples into a tuple of two lists, one for the first elements and one for the second elements:

```
{Names, _Amounts} = lists:unzip([{jill,450}, {joe,157}, {bob,100}, {sue,125}, {pat,344}]).
```

The resulting `Names` variable is bound to `[jill,joe,bob,sue,pat]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't covered list comprehensions yet, here is how to solve your problem with simple recursion:

```
-module(my).
-compile([export_all]).

firsts([]) -> [];
firsts([Tuple|Tuples]) ->
    {Name, _Amount} = Tuple,
    [Name | firsts(Tuples)].
```

Instead of your `createList()` function (and by the way, the convention is to name that function `create_list()`), you use a *list literal* in your code to create the list:

```
[Name | firsts(Tuples)]
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> Data = List = [{jill,450}, {joe,157}, {bob,100}, {sue,125}, {pat,344}].
[{jill,450},{joe,157},{bob,100},{sue,125},{pat,344}]

3> my:firsts(Data).
[jill,joe,bob,sue,pat]

4>
```

That solution takes advantage of the fact that a list can be defined like this:

```
1> [1 | [2 | [3 | []]]].
[1,2,3]
```

So this part:

```
[Name | firsts(Tuples)].
```

becomes:

```
[Name1 | ReturnValue]
```

where `ReturnValue` is what's returned by `firsts(Tuples)`, which is:

```
[Name2 | ReturnValue]
```

substituting back into the first result:

```
[Name1 | [Name2 | ReturnValue]]
```

Once again, ReturnValue is what's returned by `firsts(Tuples)`, which is:

```
[Name3 | ReturnValue]
```

substituting again gives you:

```
[Name1 | [Name2 | [Name3 | ReturnValue]]]
```

And, when ReturnValue is an empty list, you get:

```
[Name1 | [Name2 | [Name3 | [] ]]]
```

which is exactly what you need to end the list.  Compare to:

```
[1 | [2 | [3 | [] ]]].
```

Another way to do the recursion, which is generally easier to figure out, is to use an *accumulator*:

```
-module(my).
-compile([export_all]).

firsts(List) ->
    firsts(List, []).  % Add an empty list to the function call

firsts([Tuple|Tuples], Names) -> % The empty list gets assigned to Names
    {Name, _Amount} = Tuple,
    firsts(Tuples, [Name|Names]);
firsts([], Names) ->
    lists:reverse(Names).
```

`Names` is known as an *accumulator* because it is used to accumulate the results that you want to return.  Often instead of calling the variable `Names`, you will see it called `Acc` (for accumulator).

Note that these two lines:

```
firsts([Tuple|Tuples], Names) ->
    {Name, _Amount} = Tuple,
    ...
```

are normally combined into one line like this:

```
firsts([{Name, _Amount}|Tuples], Names) ->
```

For example, matching like this works:

```
27> [{Name, Amount}|Tuples] = [{jane, 250}, {bob, 100}, {kat, 150}].
[{jane,250},{bob,100},{kat,150}]

28> Name.
jane
```

which means the first solution becomes:

```
firsts([]) -> [];
firsts([{Name, _Amount}|Tuples]) ->
    [Name | firsts(Tuples)].
```

and the second solution becomes:

```
firsts(List) ->
    firsts(List, []).  % Add an empty list to the function call

firsts([{Name, _Amount}|Tuples], Names) -> % The empty list gets assigned to Names
    firsts(Tuples, [Name|Names]);
firsts([], Names) ->
    lists:reverse(Names).
```